# Foreign key relationship in Flask-Admin when using SQLAlchemy automap

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

using: python 3.4, flask-admin 1.0.8, sqlalchemy 0.9.7, latest stable mariadb/mysql backend

Yes I realize it's "experimental", but I'm trying to use sqlalchemy's automap feature to reflect an existing schema.  It appears to be working properly, except for the related record values on the admin form which show as <sqlalchemy.ext.automap...> objects.  I *believe* that a def for __unicode__ in each model class would solve the problem but not sure how to specify it when using automap.

here's the table I'm trying to edit via the Admin interface

```
CREATE TABLE `hardware_owner` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hardware_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `hardware_owner_fk_1` (`hardware_id`),
  KEY `hardware_owner_fk_2` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `hardware_owner_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`hardware_id`) REFERENCES `hardware` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `hardware_owner_fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

and here's the admin view

```
from someapp import app, db

from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask.ext.admin import Admin

Base = automap_base(metadata=db.metadata)
Base.prepare()

admin = Admin(app, name='SomeApp Admin')
admin.add_view(ModelView(Base.classes.user, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Base.classes.hardware, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Base.classes.hardware_owner, db.session))
```

In the admin create view for hardware_owner I see the proper number of options in the drop-down for user and hardware so I know it's pulling the right related rows. I just need to figure out how to specify a friendlier label than <sqlalchemy.ext.automap.(table_name) object ...> for each row.

Any suggestions?

**Update based on answer from @joes**

I'm not defining any models since automap does that so here's what I came up with to add the __str__ def to each of the classes defined by automap:

```
def obj_name_user(obj):
    return obj.username

def obj_name_hardware(obj):
    return obj.name

def obj_name_hardware_owner(obj):
    return '%s - %s' % (obj.user.username, obj.hardware.name)

Base = automap_base(metadata=db.metadata)
Base.prepare()

Base.classes.user.__str__ = obj_name_user
Base.classes.hardware.__str__ = obj_name_hardware
Base.classes.hardware_owner.__str__ = obj_name_hardware_owner
```

This works and solves my original problem, but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on python 2, add `__unicode__` to your models.

If you're on python 3 - add `__str__`.

Comment: Ah yes, \__str__ in python 3, not unicode, thanks!! But I haven't defined any model classes since automap creates them. Please refer to my update above to see how I'm adding the \__str__ def